# Clickhouse: calculating average on multiple array columns

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table which contains telemetry info such as cooling fan speeds, temperature, etc.

Telemetry is stored in arrays, because amount of cooling fans or other items is dynamic and may change from time to time and max size is unknown.

I'm trying to write a query to get average of fan speeds, temperature and power consumption for n-time (5 minutes for ex.)

Table looks like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stats
(
    `datetime`      DateTime('UTC') DEFAULT now(),
    `worker_id`     UInt64,
    `project_id`    UInt64,
    `platform_type` UInt8,
    `temp`          Array(Int32),
    `fan`           Array(Int32),
    `units`         Int32,
    `power`         Array(Float32),
    `power_total`   Float32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(datetime)
ORDER BY (worker_id, datetime);
```

Data looks like that:

```
────────────datetime─┬─worker_id─┬─temp─────────────────────────────────────┬─power─────────────────────────────────────┬─fan──────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 2021-07-26 16:37:00 │      3081 │ [51,55,53,51,56,62,58,57,55,64,63,55,61] │ [120,91,60,91,60,90,90,60,90,89,90,60,89] │ [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70] │
│ 2021-07-26 16:37:10 │      3081 │ [51,56,54,52,56,63,58,58,55,64,63,56,62] │ [120,89,60,90,60,90,89,60,88,88,90,60,90] │ [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70] │
│ 2021-07-26 16:37:20 │      3081 │ [51,56,54,52,56,63,58,58,55,64,63,56,62] │ [120,91,60,92,60,90,91,60,88,88,90,60,89] │ [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70] │
│ 2021-07-26 16:37:30 │      3081 │ [51,56,54,52,57,62,58,58,56,64,63,57,62] │ [119,90,60,92,60,90,91,60,91,88,90,60,89] │ [70,70,70,69,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70] │
│ 2021-07-26 16:37:40 │      3081 │ [51,56,55,52,57,63,58,58,56,64,63,56,62] │ [119,91,60,88,60,90,90,60,90,90,89,60,89] │ [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,68,80,80,70,70] │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I was able to write a query to get average for a single column, but struggling to write an optimal query for the rest columns.

```sql
select worker_id, round(avg(temp_value), 1) as temp_avg, temp_index
from (
      select datetime, worker_id, temp from stats
      WHERE `worker_id` = 3081
        and `datetime` between
          toDateTime('2021-07-26 19:40:00', 'UTC') AND
          toDateTime('2021-07-26 19:45:00', 'UTC')
      order by `datetime` ASC
         ) array join
     temp as temp_value,
     arrayEnumerate(temp) as temp_index
group by (worker_id, temp_index)
order by temp_index ASC;
```

Can you suggest me please an optimal query to calculate an average for `temp`, `fan`, `power` and `power_total`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [ForEach](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-foreach) aggregate function combinator:

```sql
SELECT worker_id, avgForEach(temp) temp_avg, avgForEach(power) power_avg, avgForEach(fan) fan_avg
FROM (
    /* emulate the test dataset */
    SELECT data.1 datetime, data.2 worker_id, data.3 temp, data.4 power, data.5 fan
    FROM (
        SELECT arrayJoin([
            (('2021-07-26 16:37:00'), 3081, [51,55,53,51,56,62,58,57,55,64,63,55,61], [120,91,60,91,60,90,90,60,90,89,90,60,89], [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70]),
            (('2021-07-26 16:37:10'), 3081, [51,56,54,52,56,63,58,58,55,64,63,56,62], [120,89,60,90,60,90,89,60,88,88,90,60,90], [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70]),
            (('2021-07-26 16:37:20'), 3081, [51,56,54,52,56,63,58,58,55,64,63,56,62], [120,91,60,92,60,90,91,60,88,88,90,60,89], [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70]),
            (('2021-07-26 16:37:30'), 3081, [51,56,54,52,57,62,58,58,56,64,63,57,62], [119,90,60,92,60,90,91,60,91,88,90,60,89], [70,70,70,69,70,70,70,70,70,80,80,70,70]),
            (('2021-07-26 16:37:40'), 3081, [51,56,55,52,57,63,58,58,56,64,63,56,62], [119,91,60,88,60,90,90,60,90,90,89,60,89], [70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,68,80,80,70,70])]) as data)
    )
/*WHERE {timerange condition}*/
GROUP BY worker_id

/*
┌─worker_id─┬─temp_avg───────────────────────────────────────────────┬─power_avg─────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─fan_avg──────────────────────────────────────┐
│      3081 │ [51,55.8,54,51.8,56.4,62.6,58,57.8,55.4,64,63,56,61.8] │ [119.6,90.4,60,90.6,60,90,90.2,60,89.4,88.6,89.8,60,89.2] │ [70,70,70,69.8,70,70,70,70,69.6,80,80,70,70] │
└───────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select worker_id, round(avg(temp_value), 1) as temp_avg,
                  round(avg(fan_value), 1) as fan_avg, 
                  round(avg(power_value), 1) as power_avg, 
                  temp_index
from (
      select datetime, worker_id, temp, fan, power from stats
      WHERE `worker_id` = 3081
        and `datetime` between
          toDateTime('2021-07-26 19:40:00', 'UTC') AND
          toDateTime('2021-07-26 19:45:00', 'UTC')
      order by `datetime` ASC
         ) array join
     temp as temp_value,
     fan as fan_value,
     power as power_value,
     arrayEnumerate(temp) as temp_index
group by (worker_id, temp_index)
order by temp_index ASC;




select worker_id, 
       avgForEach(temp), 
       avgForEach(fan), 
       avgForEach(power)
from stats
WHERE `worker_id` = 3081
  and `datetime` between
    toDateTime('2021-07-26 19:40:00', 'UTC') AND
    toDateTime('2021-07-26 19:45:00', 'UTC')
group by worker_id
```